# Open ACCESS 2013 with Excel VBA "Invalid Password"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Can someone advise why do I constantly get "Invalid Password" notification? The password is correct and if done manually works perfectly. I use ACCESS 2013 and Excel 2013.

```
Sub OpenACCESS()
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim intColIndex As Integer
    Dim DBFullName As String
    Dim TargetRange As Range

    DBFullName = "C:\MYDATA.accdb"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set TargetRange = Workbooks("IMD_Calculator.xlsm").Sheets("Operate").Range("A1")

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXX#1;"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM 2017, cn, , , adCmdText"

    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: The caveats at [this link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/) are worth a read. Is `XXX#1` the actual password you're using? Is `"C:\.accdb"` what you're passing it?

Comment: @Comintern I have updated the name and the PASS is very similar with # in it. Thanks for the link but I have already been to this website. I've tried multiple solutions and still facing the same issue. Perplexing to say the least.

Comment: It's possible that the `#` is a problem character for that driver - have you tried changing it to a simpler test password, like say, `test`? That would at least narrow the issue.

Comment: In what version of MS Access did you create the password? Note: this may not be the version you are currently using (i.e., 2013). I ask because starting in 2010, encryption method changed for database passwords. You may have to delete current password and use the legacy version: Access->File->Options->Client Settings->Advanced (check "use legacy encryption").

Comment: @Comintern Yes I have changed the password to "cat" and it's the same - no improvement. I went through 10's if not 100's of online sources and still can't fix it.

Comment: @Parfait in ACCESS 2013. Basically, I have created database from scratch (only for testing) and still having the same issue.

Comment: Correct because Access 2013 uses by default the new encryption. Please change with instructions above to "legacy encryption".